# Encode-Decode Issue - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption

I have issue with checking with `encrypt->encode()` and `encrypt->decode()` a string giving different result.

```
$psss = '123456';
echo $encrypted_string = $this->encrypt->encode($psss);
OUTPUT : oOUxUQgP56AUYFe4iXWTQIGjrFhTQ8Sojandl4ZF6TB3UuigUpsGrVKOLFLl+jM1++DerX0dmrzKjyrK9XyhUQ==
```

1. Above string Save to DB at password field
2. I providing password to login with `'123456'`.
3. Now I use to

   $psss = '123456'
   echo $encrypted_string = $this->encrypt->encode($psss);
4. This gives me different result.
5. How Can I compare Db string and step 5 string ???

Comment: dont use reversible methods for handling passwords look at http://www.openwall.com/phpass/

Comment: Please don't store encrypted passwords in your database. If anybody gets hold of your database and knows (or can guess) the key, they'll have access to every password that you have stored. If they have your database, what are the chances they already have access to your server and can find your key? A 1-way hash is a much safer strategy - even if they get *full access to your code and your database*, they would not be able to decode any passwords without an exhaustive hash calculation - repeated for every single user.

Comment: HI,

1. Post email and password
2. I fetch the password from Db using posted email
3. Decode that password using the `"$this->encrypt->decode($DBpass);"`
4. now compare POSTED and DECODED password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace

```
$this->encrypt->encode($pass);
```

with

```
$this->encrypt->decode($pass);
```

you need to decode the encrypted password but you again encoding it...and to encrypt your password you need to use a key and you need to use same key to decode it like

```
$key = "Some key";
$encypted = $this->encrypt->encode($pass , $key);
```

store this $encypted to your Db and decode it like

```
$this->encrypt->decode($pass , $key);
```

and you can check it like

```
$pass = $this->encrypt->encode($_REQUEST['pass']);// this change every time 
if($pass == $DB_Pass)
    echo 'Welcome user';
else
    echo 'Wrong Password';
```

Comment: Nope. It is a raw password. Should be encrypted with **salt** / **key** maybe. Or random salt / key will cause different results.

Comment: @CORRUPT I just told him the main wrong he had done,and I assumed that he will use key for encryption....its a silly thing,and no reason to downvote it

Comment: Ok ...the downvoter which done it.see my edit...I also mentioned the thngs require...

Comment: What it means..??changes every time..??

Comment: $pass = $this->encrypt->encode($_REQUEST['pass']);
every time it gives different encrypted code

Comment: no ... when we post from browser go to controller and then it changes every time using above method

Comment: at controller decode it with same key ,that you have used to store your password into DB

Comment: So i get the password for that email address and then decode that password and compare with posted password ?????????

Comment: yes,but you ned to use same key that you have used to encode it

Comment: HI,

1. Post email and password
2. I fetch the password from Db using posted email
3. Decode that password using the `"$this->encrypt->decode($DBpass);"`
4. now compare POSTED and DECODED password

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using reversible encryption, making it possible to read a password from the database and decrypt it.

A much more secure method is to use a 1-way hash such as `sha1` instead.

```
$psss = '123456';
echo $encrypted_string = sha1($psss);
```

For even more security, use a salt as well:

```
$psss = '123456';
$salt = rand(0, 1000000);
echo $encrypted_string = sha1($psss . $salt);
// save both $encrypted_string and $salt to the database
```

And to decode

```
$salt = 123; // load salt from database based on requested user id
$psss = $_POST['password'];
echo $encrypted_string = sha1($psss . $salt);
```